# Question about Eremenko's paper on iteration of entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

I have two questions about Eremenko's paper *[On the iteration of entire functions](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=GeXyx-wAAAAJ&citation_for_view=GeXyx-wAAAAJ:kRWSkSYxWN8C)*

On the second page, it says "The family $\{f^n\}=\{\underbrace{f\circ f\circ\ldots\circ f}_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not normal in $V$, hence there exists a pre-image $z^*\in V$ of one of the points $z_1,z_2$". Why does there exist such a pre-image?

[image: page2]

Also, at the bottom of that page, it mentions a set $E$ which they call an exceptional set that depends on the function $f$ and $\alpha$ that has finite logarithmic measure. What does this mean?

[image: page2b]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please try to make the question as left-contained as possible. This includes writing the definition of $\{f^n\}$, what $V$ is and what $z^\ast, z_1$ and $z_2$ are.

Comment: @AlexR: "left-contained" = "self-contained"?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Haha I must have been very sleepy ^^ Yes of course.

Answer (score 1):

If a family of entire functions omits two points $\{z_1,z_2\}$, then it's a normal family, by a [theorem of Montel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem#Functions_omitting_two_values).

Finite logarithmic measure is explained right there at the bottom of page 2, following "i.e.". It means a set $E$ such that $\int_E dt/t<\infty$.

Comment: Is this any arbitrary set $E$ that satisfies that condition? I feel that it came out of nowhere so abruptly, and it didn't give any motivation as to what it's purpose was...

Comment: Yes, it just says it's a measurable subset of $(0,\infty)$ that satisfies that condition. It's a natural condition for sets of radii and comes up often in complex analysis.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!